# Item isn't removing from array inside an input change function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my HTML code

```html
<div id="createCaseImgContainer">
  <div id="createCaseImgUploadBtn">+</div>
</div>

<div id="createCaseImgFileInputContainer">
  <input type="file" name="createCaseImg1" id="0" class="createCaseImgInput" accept="image/*" />
  <input type="file" name="createCaseImg2" id="1" class="createCaseImgInput" accept="image/*" />
  <input type="file" name="createCaseImg3" id="2" class="createCaseImgInput" accept="image/*" />
  <input type="file" name="createCaseImg4" id="3" class="createCaseImgInput" accept="image/*" />
</div>
```

Here's Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var inputs = $('.createCaseImgInput');
    var $availableInputs = [0, 1, 2, 3];
    var randomAvailableInputs = $availableInputs[Math.floor(Math.random()*$availableInputs.length)];

    $(document).on('click', '#createCaseImgUploadBtn', function() {
        $("#"+randomAvailableInputs).trigger('click');
    });

    inputs.on('change', function() {

        triggeredInputNumber = $(this).attr('id');
        removeInputNumber = parseInt(triggeredInputNumber);

        $availableInputs = $availableInputs.splice($availableInputs.indexOf(removeInputNumber), 1);

        console.log(removeInputNumber );
        console.log($availableInputs);


    });

});
```

I've created a list of numbers linked with ID for available input fields, After clicking on createCaseImgUploadBtn , it triggers any random input from the list, after selecting the file i want to remove the number from availableInputs , but its not working. Basically the whole point is that i don't want it to trigger the same file input field again after selecting the file.

Comment: `$availableInputs = $availableInputs.splice($availableInputs.indexOf(removeInputNumber), 1);` you don't need to reassign `$availableInputs` - `.splice` performs in-place deletion. When you reassign the variable, the next time you try to use it, you'll get the *result* of `splice` which is an array with the deleted items.

Comment: @VLAZ still not working, it just triggers and overwriting the same file input again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you reassign with splice. Do not need that. Just use splice. Splice changes the content of the array

[Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Second, you initialize the `randomAvailableInputs` value on `document.ready`. The value will stay the same at every click you make on the button.

You need to give a value to `randomAvailableInputs` when clicking on the button so that value changes according to the `$availableInputs` array.

Check below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var inputs = $('.createCaseImgInput');
  var $availableInputs = [0, 1, 2, 3];



  $(document).on('click', '#createCaseImgUploadBtn', function() {
    // move this here
    var randomAvailableInputs = $availableInputs[Math.floor(Math.random() * $availableInputs.length)];
    $("#" + randomAvailableInputs).trigger('click');
  });

  inputs.on('change', function() {

    triggeredInputNumber = $(this).attr('id');
    removeInputNumber = parseInt(triggeredInputNumber);

    $availableInputs.splice($availableInputs.indexOf(removeInputNumber), 1);

    console.log(removeInputNumber);
    console.log($availableInputs);


  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="createCaseImgContainer">
  <div id="createCaseImgUploadBtn">CLICK ME</div>
</div>

<div id="createCaseImgFileInputContainer">
  <input type="file" name="createCaseImg1" id="0" class="createCaseImgInput" accept="image/*" />
  <input type="file" name="createCaseImg2" id="1" class="createCaseImgInput" accept="image/*" />
  <input type="file" name="createCaseImg3" id="2" class="createCaseImgInput" accept="image/*" />
  <input type="file" name="createCaseImg4" id="3" class="createCaseImgInput" accept="image/*" />
</div>
```

Comment: Its working now, Haha really didnt notice that ! Thank you so much

Comment: Yep. You always get the same value on that `randomAvailableInputs ` because it's been given a value at `document.ready` and never changed after that. That's why you need to give it a value dynamically on click. Glad i could help.

Comment: well not really. It's a simple code. You should declare your variables with `var` ( or const/let ). `triggeredInputNumber` and `removeInputNumber` . Check here http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html. And also have consistency in naming your variables ( with/without `$` in front ) . The click function instead of `document` you can use `this` as it will refer to the document, being directly in a document.ready function. But you could change the click function to be applied directly to the button `$(button).on('click', function() { )}` or `$(button).click`